# How to post an image to Twitter with PHP?

Tags: php, curl, twitter

I'm trying to post a message with an image to Twitter through PHP and cURL. It's working for the message but I don't know how to add the image to it.

From the [documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/post/statuses/update_with_media):

> Unlike POST statuses/update, this method
>   expects raw multipart data. Your POST request's Content-Type should be
>   set to multipart/form-data with the media[] parameter

This is the PHP:

```
<?php
class Tweet {
public $url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update_with_media.json';

function the_nonce(){
    $nonce = base64_encode(uniqid());
    $nonce = preg_replace('~[\W]~','',$nonce);
    return $nonce;
}

function get_DST($status){

    $url = $this->url;

    $consumer_key = "[removed]";
    $nonce = $this->the_nonce();
    $sig_method = 'HMAC-SHA1';
    $timestamp = time();
    $version = "1.0";
   $token = "[removed]";
    $access_secret = "[removed]";
    $consumer_secret =  "[removed]";

    $param_string = 'oauth_consumer_key='.$consumer_key.
            '&oauth_nonce='.$nonce.
            '&oauth_signature_method='.$sig_method.
            '&oauth_timestamp='.$timestamp.
            '&oauth_token='.$token.
            '&oauth_version='.$version.
            '&status='.rawurlencode($status);
    $sig_base_string = 'POST&'.rawurlencode($url).'&'.rawurlencode($param_string);
    $sig_key = rawurlencode($consumer_secret).'&'.rawurlencode($access_secret);

    $tweet_sig = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $sig_base_string, $sig_key, true));

    $DST = 'OAuth oauth_consumer_key="'.rawurlencode($consumer_key).'",'.
        'oauth_nonce="'.rawurlencode($nonce).'",'.
        'oauth_signature="'.rawurlencode($tweet_sig).'",'.
        'oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",'.
        'oauth_timestamp="'.rawurlencode($timestamp).'",'.
        'oauth_token="'.rawurlencode($token).'",'.
        'oauth_version="1.0"';
    return $DST;
}

function set($status){
$url = $this->url;
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: ' . $this->get_DST($status)));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'status='.rawurlencode($status));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$result = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
$resultString =  print_r($result,true);;
curl_close($ch);
}

$status->set("hello");
?>
```

How to add the *media[]* part to it?

Comment: i'm doing this (without curl) using [Twitter OAuth](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/oauth/faq) i upload the image to my server, get the route of the image, add the page link to it and send to the function, does that type of solution works for you? if so, i will post Some code in order to help you.

Comment: I would go with the @DannyG solution. It's not as elegant but the result is the same, and it's more straightforward to implement.

Comment: @DannyG That would work, thanks! I'm looking forward to your code.

Comment: @Jay Sorry for the time, i was out of the city, there is my answer see if it works for you. im using this to publish the new updated products on a E-Store.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if [Matt Harris](https://github.com/themattharris/tmhOAuth)' library would do for you, but the code is rather simple

```
require_once ('your_app_tokens.php');
require_once ('tmhOAuth.php');

$connection = new tmhOAuth(array(
  'consumer_key'    => $consumer_key,
  'consumer_secret' => $consumer_secret,
  'user_token'      => $user_token,  //stored in session or whatever else
  'user_secret'     => $User_secret
));
$message ="test";
    $image = "image.jpg"; // must be in the same directory
    $extension = "jpg";
        $post = $connection->request(
          'POST',
         'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update_with_media.json',
          array(
            'media[]'  => "@{$image};type=image/{$extension};filename={$image}",
            'status'   => $message
          ),


     true,
              true
            );
            $code = $connection->response;

//if the code is 200 it's all fine
```

Answer (score -1):

i've created a script that allows you to post a tweet with image. I'm using the php fonction that used an url to upload the image to your server. After that, it upload from your server to the twitter one. You got an image ID that you can use to send a tweet with a picture.

Here is my github projet. Everything is inside, easy to used and install.

https://github.com/florianchapon/twitter-poster